# c# .Net DateTimePicker problem

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

this is what I am doing,

```
//this doesnt set the datetimepicker value to the set value 
class{
   constructor
   {
      InitializeComponent(); // -> this initializes all the form components

      DateTimePicker.Value = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(30); //->trying to set the date time picker value to a date one month from now.

   }
}

//but this does set the date to the desired value..
class{
   constructor
   {
      InitializeComponent(); // -> this initializes all the form components

   }

   form_onLoad() //->on form load event
   {
     DateTimePicker.Value = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
   }
}
```

Can someone please explain whats the difference and why it doesnt change date with previous method? and why it sets with the latter method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time you use this line:

`DateTimePicker.Value = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);`

is before the form loads, in the form constructor. When the form actually loads, the value is reset. You can't manipulate controls in the instantiation code of the container.

Answer (score 1):

DateTimePicker is a property of your form. You can not set any value of any property of form before it loads. So your 1st one doesn't work and the 2nd one does.